# SSIS destination tables being blocked. How to prevent this

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, locking

**ISSUE** Destination tables in the package get locked by other processes frequently and this leads to long run time ( >12 hrs).

**Scenario** : I have a SSIS package. It has sequence containers - containing approx. 110 tasks which run sequentially (are either data flow or execute SQL tasks) and write data from different sources to a MS Sql Server db. The database is used by matlab and reporting processes also, and the same tables are used by  their queries.

**Desired outcome :** I would like to exclude all users/processes out of the database for the period the package is running and allow them in only after package has executed.

**Solutions attempted so far**: Before the SSIS executes, I have a script which kills all user sessions in the destination db but this has not been very successful.

Comment: Your title and description conflict. Your title says you **don't** want the tables locked, but your description says you do?

Comment: Thanks much. Clarified.

Answer (score 0):

At one place that I worked, we had a SQL Agent job set up to run every twenty minutes from midnight to 04:00 that would kill any sessions from "unauthorized" users in the data warehouse during the build process.

Something along these lines. I'm working from memory:

```
DECLARE @spid integer;

DECLARE spids CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT 
   session_id
  FROM 
   msdb.sys.dm_exec_sessions
  WHERE 
    nt_user_name NOT IN (/*White List of Logins*/ 'sa');

OPEN spids
FETCH NEXT FROM spids INTO @spid
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  KILL @spid;
FETCH NEXT FROM spids INTO @spid
END;

CLOSE spids;
DEALLOCATE spids;
```

In the White List section, add all the logins that your build processes use, that your maintenance procedures use, etc. The list at that employer was short enough that we kept it hard coded in the job, but you could create a table for it. You could also pick up additional data from the DMVs, from who was logged in to the query they were running, and log all of that.